# How to send my UITextfield to a variable via an UIButton?

Tags: iphone, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uilabel

I want to know how can I type something in my UITextfield and then send it to a variable via an UIButton?

When I try it with this code the app automatically crashes and show me this error:

> Thread:1 signal SIGABRT

Here's the code:

```
  import UIKit
  import Foundation

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var LabelHeure: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Heure: UITextField!

@IBAction func Send(sender: AnyObject) {
     var one = String(Heure.text)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    LabelHeure.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(),dateStyle:NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle,timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

}
```

Comment: What do you want set to the text entered in Heure? LabelHeure?

Comment: Is your `Heure` outlet actually connected to the text field control in interface builder? There should be circle next to it in the editor. Empty means it is not connected, filled means it is connected. If not connected, similar errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cast Heure.text as a string because it is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used and it worked. After pressing the button, the variable is updated with the text from the textfield. I used a println to verify.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var LabelHeure: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Heure: UITextField!

@IBAction func Send(sender: AnyObject) {

    var myVariable = Heure.text
    println(myVariable)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.





}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

}

Comment: Thank you , but still have an SIGABRT error i verified all the connection... Still don't understand...

Comment: Try restarting Xcode and then cleaning the project. Sometimes this happens.

Comment: de rien :) comment back here if you need help again and I'll take another look!

Comment: Ok ! C'est très gentil ;) !

Comment: I just want to know if there is a method  to register my UITextfield content in a different variable every different day ?